# I can't able to click the button Simultaneously from one after another in this app ...Please tell me what is the reason

Tags: java, android

I created this Remote app for controlling TV using Aurdino what is the problem is I can't able to click the button Simultaneously from one after another in this app .
Please tell me what is the reason....
I can only able to click the button only once after that the app will suddenly closed, So please help me how to solve this problem...

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String SERVERPORT = "85";
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "11.253.139.16";

    Button bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5, bt6, bt7, bt8, bt9, bt0;
    Button start, retrn, list, up, right, left, okey, down, forward;
    Button volup, voldown, backward, mute, menu,
            tvav, sleep, picture, sound, qv, zoom, display, play, stop;

    ClientAsyncTask clientAST = new ClientAsyncTask();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        bt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        bt5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        bt6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        bt7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        bt8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        bt9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        bt0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        retrn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rtn);
        list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list);
        up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
        right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
        left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
        okey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
        forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.frwd);
        backward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bkwd);
        mute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mute);
        menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu);
        volup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.volup);
        voldown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.voldown);
        tvav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvav);
        sleep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sleep);
        picture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picture);
        sound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sound);
        qv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.qv);
        zoom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Zoom);
        display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Display);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        tvav.setOnClickListener(this);
        sleep.setOnClickListener(this);
        picture.setOnClickListener(this);
        sound.setOnClickListener(this);
        qv.setOnClickListener(this);
        zoom.setOnClickListener(this);
        display.setOnClickListener(this);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt3.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt4.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt5.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt6.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt7.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt8.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt9.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt0.setOnClickListener(this);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        retrn.setOnClickListener(this);
        list.setOnClickListener(this);
        up.setOnClickListener(this);
        left.setOnClickListener(this);
        right.setOnClickListener(this);
        okey.setOnClickListener(this);
        down.setOnClickListener(this);
        forward.setOnClickListener(this);
        backward.setOnClickListener(this);
        volup.setOnClickListener(this);
        voldown.setOnClickListener(this);
        mute.setOnClickListener(this);
        menu.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            String btn1_CODE = "1";
            // out.println(btn1_CODE);
            Sendittoserver(btn1_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            String btn2_CODE = "2";
            Sendittoserver(btn2_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.btn3:
            String btn3_CODE = "3";
            Sendittoserver(btn3_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.btn4:
            String btn4_CODE = "4";
            Sendittoserver(btn4_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.btn5:
            String btn5_CODE = "5";
            Sendittoserver(btn5_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.btn6:
            String btn6_CODE = "6";
            Sendittoserver(btn6_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.btn7:
            String btn7_CODE = "7";
            Sendittoserver(btn7_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.btn8:
            String btn8_CODE = "8";
            Sendittoserver(btn8_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.btn9:
            String btn9_CODE = "9";
            Sendittoserver(btn9_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.btn0:
            String btn0_CODE = "0";
            Sendittoserver(btn0_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.rtn:
            String rtn_CODE = "";
            Sendittoserver(rtn_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.list:
            String list_CODE = "";
            Sendittoserver(list_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.up:
            String up_CODE = "G";
            Sendittoserver(up_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.left:
            String left_CODE = "H";
            Sendittoserver(left_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.right:
            String right_CODE = "K";
            Sendittoserver(right_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.ok:
            String ok_CODE = "F";
            Sendittoserver(ok_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.down:
            String down_CODE = "J";
            Sendittoserver(down_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.frwd:
            String frwd_CODE = "C";
            Sendittoserver(frwd_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.bkwd:
            String bkwd_CODE = "V";
            Sendittoserver(bkwd_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.volup:
            String volup_CODE = "B";
            Sendittoserver(volup_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.voldown:
            String voldown_CODE = "N";
            Sendittoserver(voldown_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.mute:
            String mute_CODE = "U";
            Sendittoserver(mute_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.menu:
            String menu_CODE = "M";
            Sendittoserver(menu_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.start:
            String start_CODE = "P";
            Sendittoserver(start_CODE);
            //Todo....
            break;
        case R.id.tvav:
            String tvav_CODE = "T";
            Sendittoserver(tvav_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.sleep:
            String sleep_CODE = "L";
            Sendittoserver(sleep_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.picture:
            String picture_CODE = "I";
            Sendittoserver(picture_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.Sound:
            String sound_CODE = "S";
            Sendittoserver(sound_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.qv:
            String qv_CODE = "A";
            Sendittoserver(qv_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.Zoom:
            String zoom_CODE = "Z";
            Sendittoserver(zoom_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.Display:
            String display_CODE = "D";
            Sendittoserver(display_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.play:
            String play_CODE = "O";
            Sendittoserver(play_CODE);
            break;
        case R.id.stop:
            String stop_CODE = "Y";
            Sendittoserver(stop_CODE);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Trace?  The sexy Cat called LogCat?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this code looks ugly.

Comment: add method Sendittoserver also

Comment: The code actually is very poor!

Answer (score 0):

I assume in your `Sendittoserver` method you have (since you declared on top `ClientAsyncTask clientAST = new ClientAsyncTask();`):

```
clientAST.execute(params);
```

it should be:

```
new ClientAsyncTask().execute(params);
```

Since you need to create a new `AsyncTask` for each request.